# Rellenar una columna a partir de varias columnas sin reemplazar su contenido

Tags: python, pandas

Tengo un df con varias columnas. Una de ellas habla del idioma del texto y otra de ellas de la localización de su autor.

Quiero crear una columna que sea "Español", y su contenido será "SI" o "NO". Para ello, necesito pasar por la columna del texto. Si aparece "es" (significa que el texto está escrito en español), en la columna "Español" tiene que aparecer "SI". Si aparece otro idioma (en, fr...), la celda se llena con un "NO".

Hasta ahí no hay ningún problema.

```
def español(e):
    if e["Texto_Lang"] == "es":
        return "SI"
    else:
        return "NO"
```

Todo bien. Sin embargo, hay españoles que han escrito en otros idiomas, pero en la columna "localizacion" tienen puesto "España". He hecho el mismo proceso que veis arriba, pero lo que sucede es que se sustituyen los valores de la columna "español" en este nuevo proceso, cuando lo que necesito es que si aparece "es" en idioma o "España" en localización (cualquiera de las dos), en la columna "español" aparezca "SI".

No sé si mes estoy explicando. ¿Alguien me puede ayudar con esto?

Muchas gracias a todos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplemente añade `or` y la otra condición que quieres admitir, así te pondrá SI tanto para uno como para el otro

```
def español(e):
    if e["Texto_Lang"] == "es" or e['localizacion'] == 'España':
        return "SI"
    else:
        return "NO"
```

Comment: En el clavo. Solucionado. ¡Muchísimas gracias!

Answer (score 2):

De forma mas eficiente puedes utilizar condiciones, que son siempre más recomendables que el uso de `apply` principalmente por que este método se vuelve muy lento con dataframes grandes.

```
# Creamos el dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({"lenguaje": ["es", "es", "ing", "fr", "es", "ing", "Español"]})

# Definimos las condiciones
IDIOMA = "Español"

condicion_es = df["lenguaje"]=="es" 
condicion_español = df["lenguaje"]=="Español"

df.loc[:,IDIOMA] = condicion_es|condicion_español

# Reemplazamos los booleanos por Si y No
df[IDIOMA] = df[IDIOMA].replace({True: 'Si', False: 'No'})
df
        lenguaje    Español
    0   es            Si
    1   es            Si
    2   ing           No
    3   fr            No
    4   es            Si
    5   ing           No
    6   Español       Si
```

Si quisieras añadir más condiciones simplemente tendrias que seguir añadiendo más  condiciones despues del operador |, de la siguiente forma

```
df.loc[:, IDIOMA] = condicion1|condicion2|condicion3|...
```

Comment: Boh, ¡perfecto! Muchas gracias!